# CPU Info from top command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This the output of top command:

```
Mem: 245108K used, 784400K free, 6636K shrd, 15128K buff, 41824K cached
CPU:  12% usr   0% sys   0% nic  87% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 2.62 2.58 2.57 2/90 29509
```

I need a single line script command to execute and get the "CPU" line.

I can get the Mem line from "cat /proc/meminfo" and Load average from "cat /proc/loadavg".

Is there any way to get the same for CPU.

Comment: "from top command" is a bit misleading, if you actually want to pull the data from procfs (which is certainly the better practice).

Comment: I need only the information. I can use it from procfs too

Comment: ...so, it's absolutely available from there, but the tricky thing is that it's only measurable *over time*. Note how there's a delay between when you run `top` and when it first displays those statistics? There's a reason for that: It collects an initial counter value from the kernel, waits a bit, and then collects a new counter and divides its value by the amount of time that happened between the two collection events. Which is to say that for this particular data, the kernel doesn't do the job of providing it in a "for the last second" form.

Comment: ...you can absolutely run that same logic yourself, but if you're expecting to be able to get an instant result vs the poll-wait-poll-calculate loop...

Comment: I need instant result..so i better use top

Comment: ...then you'll probably want to have a separate daemon that's built for the purpose (and there are plenty of tools that are well-suited for the job!) maintaining the numbers for you.

Comment: As I told you, **top isn't instant**. Its first screen refresh (in versions that don't delay before displaying the screen at all) doesn't have all the numbers you're asking for; they're only available on the second refresh, which happens later.

Comment: top -b -n 1 |grep CPU | head -1 will this not work, even it is not the correct one.

Comment: ...if you're going to continue ignoring what I say, perhaps you might want to read the `vmstat` documentation while you do so? Unlike `top`, its output is intended to be usable for scripted consumption and so is less liable to change without notice between releases.

Answer (score 0):

@md.jamal -- Try this, to get top 10 most current utilizing resources process Ids with %CPU and %MEM.

```
    ps -eo pid,ppid,%cpu,%mem | sort -rnk3 | head

Below is details for above command:

where ps --> reports snapshot of current process
-e --> select all processes
-o --> output format
sort -r --> reverse sort, ie descending order
sort -n --> numeric sort
sort -k3 --> to select column no:3
head --> to display top 10 records
```

Comment: Not what is being requested.

Comment: Sorry. That's arguments are not been supported by 'ps' command on my target machine